# How to apply language switch option to all pages? (Django project)

Tags: html, django, redirect, django-views, multilingual

So I have this Django project that contains home page and a few other pages:
My home page file looks like:

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% trans 'Blog' %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-image"
     style="background-image: linear-gradient( 112.1deg,  rgba(32,38,57,1) 11.4%, rgba(63,76,119,1) 70.2% );">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{% trans 'Blog' %}</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Navigation switch">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">{% trans 'Main' %}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">{% trans 'About blog' %}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                               data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                {% trans 'Blog sections' %}
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/pozn">{% trans 'Section1' %}</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/len">{% trans 'Не Section2' %}</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/superlren">{% trans 'Super section' %}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                           data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            {% trans 'language' %}
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="g-image" style="background-image: linear-gradient( 112.1deg,  rgba(32,38,57,1) 11.4%, rgba(63,76,119,1) 70.2% );">
                            <br>
                            **<form action="{% url 'home' %}">>
                                <textarea name="text1" cols="5" rows="1"></textarea><br/>
                                <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary', value="Submit"/>
                            </form>**
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="{% url 'signup'  %}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Sign up' %}</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    {% block content %}
        {% for post in object_list %}
            <div style="margin-top: 1%">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row align-items-start">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="bg-image card shadow-1-strong"
                                 style="background-image: radial-gradient( circle 369px at -2.9% 12.9%,  rgba(247,234,163,1) 0%, rgba(236,180,238,0.56) 46.4%, rgba(163,203,247,1) 100.7% );">
                                <div class="card-body text-white">
                                    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                    <a href="{% url 'profile_page' post.author.username %}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Author:' %} {{ post.author }}</button>
                                    </a>
                                    <p>{% trans 'Submitted by:' %} <b>{{ post.author }}</b></p>
                                    <p>{{ post.body|truncatechars:1000 }}</p>
                                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'More' %}</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock content %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in my home page HTML file I have this form where user enters the needed language and submits it, after that the text they enter is passed to the following function in views.py file:

```
def translatet(request):
    text = request.GET['text1']
    if text == 'English':
        translation.activate('en')
    elif text == 'German':
        activate('de')
    elif text == 'Spanish':
        activate('es')
    elif text == 'Italian':
        activate('it')
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

I already prepared django.po file and updated it. After user clicks submit the page reloads in a different language. The problem is after it reloaded all the content and background of the page disappears, so what I have left is the Blog, About, Sections (so the head of the project). Also when I click other pages it appears in initial language.

I tried changing urls but it didn't help. At the moment my url patterns are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('about/', AboutPageView .as_view(), name='about'),
    path('', Bloglist.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', profile, name='profile_page'),
    path('user/registration/', registration, name='signup'),
    path('post/profile/<str:username>/', sign_inf, name='signup_info'),
    path('en/home', translatet,  name="home"),

]
```

What I expect is the pages to look correctly (fix the problem with disappearance of the content) and for the submitted language to apply to all of the pages, not just current one with the form.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you guys